# libGDX - Scene2d Actions or Frame Animation, which is better for performance?

Tags: libgdx, animation, performance, scene2d

I only use Scene2d for the UI layer of my libGDX game. But I need some animations like fading or rotating on my players.

Which is better for performance:

Scene2d fade action or having multiple frames with different opacity and using them in the Animation class?

Also scene2d rotate action or having multiple frames with different angle?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I write in *LibGDX* for a while and in my opinion it's better to write players movement/rotation/jumping in the code directly and leave `Actions` for the UI.

It depends if it's a single-player game like a platformer, or a fast-paced multiplayer game, but usually you should not use `Actions` for the player because Actions are pooled/queued and they'll be slower than the manual setup.

Rotation and fading can be made on `Actions` or [Universal Tween Engine](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Universal-Tween-Engine) but if you need more elements in the future like jumping/shooting and custom, precise interpolation for movement you should have your own system.

- Actions for the UI
- Manual for the player's movement/jumping/input etc.